# Why do I lose messages after reconnecting to Apache Apollo MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, apollo

I have installed Apollo v1.7.1 and am using the Paho Go client to publish from one connection and subscribe from another. When I connect the subscriber with a new clientid or when I connect the subscriber with an existing clientid and set the clean flag to true, everything works as it should.

However, if I connect the subscriber attempting to reuse a clientid with a clean flag of false, the subscriber begins to lose most of the messages sent by the publisher. Some of the messages are sent, but most are not.

I can see from the html console that the messages are received from the publishers by Apollo. I can also see when it sends the messages that make it to the subscriber, but I can't figure out why it's not sending all of the messages.

Is there a problem with Apollo or is the client doing something wrong?

Comment: I just duplicated my test using the same clients but connecting to RabbitMQ with their MQTT adapter and it works as expected. I believe this problem is with Apollo itself.

Comment: What QOS levels are you using?

Comment: I've tried them all. For what I'm doing, QOS 1 and 2 are the only ones relevant. I need to be able to reconnect after a lost connection and retrieve messages that accumulated while not connected.

Comment: OK, just making sure it wasn't just an artefact of a QOS 0 implementation